# How to extract numbers line by line while reading a text file in matlab

Tags: matlab

I want to extract numbers from a file but I don't know why `s` is still empty. While reading the text file, I want to skip the 9 first lines, 
then to read line by line and extract a number between two space characters after the `:` character.

Here is the code:

```
[fid, message]=fopen('info1.txt','r');
x=fread(fid,'char=>char');
%skip the 9 first lines of the file
for i=1:9
    fgetl(fid);
end
tline = fgets(fid);
s=[];
j=1;
while ischar(tline)
    disp(tline); 
    tline = fgetl(fid); %read line by line
    i=1;
    while double(tline(i))~=13
        if(tline(i)==':')
            while tline(i+1)~=' '
                s(j)=s(j)+tline(i+1);
            end
        else i=i+1;
        end
    end
    j=j+1;
end
```

Here is the text file.

```
-- Voice report for 1. Sound AXH1NAL --
Date: Fri Feb 27 13:46:32 2015

WARNING: some of the following measurements may be imprecise.
For more precision, go to "Pitch settings" and choose "Optimize for voice analysis".

Time range of SELECTION
   From 0 to 3.000020 seconds (duration: 3.000020 seconds)
Pitch:
   Median pitch: 239.912 Hz
   Mean pitch: 239.651 Hz
   Standard deviation: 2.029 Hz
   Minimum pitch: 233.314 Hz
   Maximum pitch: 243.288 Hz
Pulses:
   Number of pulses: 713
   Number of periods: 712
   Mean period: 4.172732E-3 seconds
   Standard deviation of period: 0.036479E-3 seconds
Voicing:
   Fraction of locally unvoiced frames: 0   (0 / 297)
   Number of voice breaks: 0
   Degree of voice breaks: 0   (0 seconds / 3.000020 seconds)
Jitter:
   Jitter (local): 0.218%
   Jitter (local, absolute): 9.104E-6 seconds
   Jitter (rap): 0.118%
   Jitter (ppq5): 0.134%
   Jitter (ddp): 0.353%
Shimmer:
   Shimmer (local): 1.018%
   Shimmer (local, dB): 0.089 dB
   Shimmer (apq3): 0.551%
   Shimmer (apq5): 0.684%
   Shimmer (apq11): 0.779%
   Shimmer (dda): 1.653%
Harmonicity of the voiced parts only:
   Mean autocorrelation: 0.997744
   Mean noise-to-harmonics ratio: 0.002262
   Mean harmonics-to-noise ratio: 26.891 dB
```

Comment: So the problem is only with extracting the numbers, otherwise the lines look ok?

Comment: Would help if you could show a sample line from the file. You don't perform type conversions and have an unusual operation  `s(j)=s(j)+tline(i+1);` in there

Comment: Ok, could you include line termination markers? It's not clear where lines end. I'll give a shot at editing it for you...

Answer (score 0):

This is a rewrite of your function, but the key point is the use of `regexp`.

```
fid = fopen('data.txt','r');
text=fread(fid,[1 Inf],'int8');
fclose(fid);
text=char(text);
text=strsplit(text,char(10)); 
text(1:9) = [];
values = regexp(text,'.*\:\s*([\d\.\+\-E]+).*$','tokens');  % <-- use ME!!
array = str2num(char(cell2mat(cell2mat(values(~cellfun('isempty',values))))));
```

You can keep your own function and as you traverse the file line by line you can use that same `regexp` command to extract the numbers. You will then need to test whether anything was found in the line, with `cellfun('isempty',values)`; then, if its not empty, extract the char-format numbers from the cell array and convert to numeric format, with `str2num(values{1}{1})`. But the code here does everything in one swoop.

I keep the code compact, which might make debugging a little tricky if you get in trouble. If you find it doesn't work split things up:

```
fid = fopen('data.txt','r');
text=fread(fid,[1 Inf],'int8');
fclose(fid);
text=char(text);
text=strsplit(text,char(10)); 
text(1:9) = [];
values = regexp(text,'.*:\s*([\d\.\+\-E]+).*$','tokens');
ind =~cellfun('isempty',values);
array = cell2mat(cell2mat(values(ind)));
array = str2num(char(array))
```

If you want to loop line by line through your file, you can extract numbers as follows:

```
  values = regexp(line,'.*:\s*([\d\.\+\-E]+).*$','tokens');
 if ~cellfun('isempty',values)
    s(j) = str2num(values{1}{1});
 end
```

Comment: @emily ok, I'm splitting it up into smaller bits, maybe you can provide more feedback as to where you get an error message

Comment: @emily Is `values` empty?

Comment: values is also empty.

Comment: @emily well then assuming *text* is not empty and is created as in my answer, then the regexp command is not working for you, but I can't understand why, maybe it's a version or platform thing. Can you test if the regexp command works for a simple string like `s = 'Minimum pitch: 233.314 Hz'` run as  `regexp(s,'.*:\s*([\d\.\+\-E]+).*$','tokens')`

Comment: Good, then you get a value for `values`. Then you need to extract your numbers from the resulting cell array. That's what the remaining code does.

Comment: Ok then I can add an explanation for how to extract the numbers from a line of your file...